# How do I disable a button after it's clicked in wxpython?

Tags: python, event-handling, wxpython

There are two buttons in my little program, start and stop. And what I want is to disable the start button after I click it, and when I hit the stop button it should return to normal. How can I do this? I googled for a while and couldn't find the answer, hope you guys can help me out.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the button's `Enable` and `Disable` methods in the appropriate event handlers.  There's a sample available at the link below:

> [wxPython Button Demo](http://www.daniweb.com/code/snippet216737.html)
>
> In this snippet we are playing around with wxPython's buttons, showing you how to bind the mouse click event, enable and disable, show and hide the buttons. Each button also has a tool-tip (hint) associated with itself.